# Simple maximization problem with binary variables

Tags: mathematical-optimization

I tried to solve an integer-linear optimization problem but failed. I reduced the failed example to the following:

```
FindMaximum[{x + y, Element[x , {0, 1}], Element[y , {0, 1}]}, {x, y}]
```

I got the following error:

```
FindMaximum::elemc: Unable to resolve the domain or region membership condition x\[Element]{0,1}.
```

I get the same error when using `NMaximize` instead of `FindMaximum`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: does `NMaximize[{x + y, 0<=x<=1,0<=y<=1}, {x, y}, Integers]` work?

Comment: also `FindMaximum[{x + y,x<=1,y<=1, Element[{x,y},Integers]}, {x, y}]`

Comment: @kglr yes, it works! Thanks.

Comment: Voting to close because I think the "elemc" message and the [`FindMaximum`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindMaximum.html) function page hint why OP's command does not work. Although, I might be wrong...

Comment: see also [Minimise discrete function](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/173612/34893).

Comment: In Mathematica, and unlike in mathematics, `{1,2}` is not a set, but a list.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
NMaximize[{x + y, 0<=x<=1,0<=y<=1}, {x, y}, Integers] (* or *)
FindMaximum[{x + y,x<=1,y<=1, Element[{x,y},Integers]}, {x, y}]
```

both give

> {2., {x -> 1, y -> 1}}

Comment: Thanks.  I still do not understand why my command did not work, but this solved my problem.